# javax.xml.xpath.XPath.evalute method could not resolve simple xpath

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I need to design a utility which searches node using input xpath in XML document and set its value as per given input.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
public class XMLUtil 
{

        private XPath xPath;
        private Document xmlDoc;
        private String xmlName;

        public XMLUtil(String xmlName) {
            this.xmlName = xmlName;
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File srcXMLFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + xmlName);
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                xmlDoc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(srcXMLFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        }

        public void changeXMLNodeValue(String xpath, String query) {
            try {
                        
            Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(xpath).evaluate(xmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            node.setTextContent(query);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        XMLUtil xmlUtil = new XMLUtil("tc01.xml"); 
    xmlUtil.changeXMLNodeValue("//Customer/State/City","Hyderabad");
    }
    }
```

XML File:tc01.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer>
<State>
<value>Andhra</value>
<City>
<value>amravati</value>
</City>
</State>
</Customer>
```

> Running the code is throwing NullPointerException at changeXMLNodeValue method on trying to compile and evalute the xpath to fetch the node.
> Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(xpath).evaluate(xmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);

This is a simple xml without any namespace requirement.
I am using the API first please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: I doubt that you tried to run the code you pasted as the syntax obviously is incorrect. Please fix the formatting of your post.

Comment: @MatthiasWiehl : fixed the formatting and compiler errors.

Comment: Your XML has `City/value` but you're only attempting the text content of `City`, there is no `TextContent` for City, you need to go one level deeper.

Comment: @kendavidson: I tried with the xpath "//Customer/State/City/value" but still the issue persists.

Comment: Works fine for me at https://github.com/martin-honnen/XPathSO75057126, outputs the changed XML as e.g. `<Customer><State><value>Andhra</value><City><value>Hyderabad</value></City></State></Customer>`